# How to find the special characters in a string and replace them

Tags: c#, string

I have a requirement where I have to replace the database names in the dynamic sql with the new database names. something like

```
select * from DBName.TableName
```

needs to be converted to

```
select * from newDBName.TableName
```

—-

```
select * from [DbName.TableName]
```

needs to be converted to

```
select * from [NewDbName.TableName]
```

Comment: [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: `string NewString = OldString.Replace("DBName", "newDBName")`

Comment: Could you also add the sample code where these names need to be replaced?

Comment: To avoid other change, use `string NewString = OldString.Replace(@"DbName.", @"NewDbName.");` . Take note at character `.`

Comment: why do you ask the same question twice? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50732185

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple String.Replace may not solve your problem as the search text may be present at other places where you don't wish to change.

The safe way to do this kind of transformation is to parse the SQL statements and perform a contextual replace.

Comment: I ended up writing my own method which would find the location of all the dnNames first and then check if after or before that DBName is it a valid DBName which can be replaced with new DBName.

Answer (score 0):

This is arguably an excellent use case for a Regular Expression. I suggest the following minimalistic pattern:

```
(?i)\bDbname\b
```

The idea here is to use word boundaries `\b` and an inline `(?i)` case-insensitive modifier to match the string in any case.

A more involved pattern could look like this:

```
(?i)(?<=\[|\b)DBNAME(?=\b|\])
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LqRSvs/1)

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/m287sK)

To be more strict, we could add an additional front anchor, e.g. `FROM`

```
(?<=FROM\s+\[?)Dbname(?=\..+?\]?\b)
```

**Explanation**:

- `(?<=FROM\s+\[?)` a positive lookbehind to use the keyword `FROM` as an anchor, one or more whitespace `\s` characters follow, then an optional `]`
- `Dbname` the literal string in question
- `(?=\..+?\]?\b)` a positive lookahead that spans the table name till the next word boundary `\b` appears

I use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) because they do not contribute the match result `$0`. This makes it easy to use in a replace.

[Code Sample](https://ideone.com/8ZTtyg):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(?<=FROM\s+\[?)(Dbname)(?=\..+?\]?)";
        string substitution = @"newDbName";
        string input = @"select * from DBName.TableName
select * from [DbName.TableName]";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see this will work. But fails when used to parse this query : select * from [DbName].[TableName]  . I ended up writing my own method which would find the location of all the dnNames first and then check if after or before that DBName is it a valid DBName which can be replaced with new DBName.

Comment: @KrishanKaliraman I don't see why the first suggestion should not work. Added an additional version.